# What is the algebraic way to solve inequalities like this: $|x+4|<2x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

What is the algebraic way to solve inequalities like this: $|x+4|<2x$?

Can I rewrite this as $-2x<x+4<2x$ or [$x+4<2x$ and $-(x+4)<2x$]?

I found out that the answer was $x>4$, but how can I do it algebraically instead of by inspection? I also did some algebra that lead me to $x>{-4\over 3}$ when I considered $-(x+4)<2x$, this can't be right.

Comment: *“Can I rewrite this as $-2x<x+4<2x$”* – yes, you can.

Comment: @AsherAbraham We know from the outset that $x>0$.

Comment: @AsherAbraham What's wrong if we put $x=-10$? $-2x<x+4<2x$ then fails, as does $|x+4|<2x$

Comment: @mrsamy I know, I just meant how do I know it is $x>4$ and not $x>-4/3$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales how do we know that $x>0$? Is this by inspection?

Comment: Because $0\le|x+4|<2x$ so $0<2x$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales ahh duh lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your latter rewriting is correct and (in my opinion) the best one. Once you have that

$$\text{both} \; \begin{cases}
x+4 < 2x \\
-(x+4) < 2x
\end{cases}$$

solve each inequality for $x$. You get

$$\text{both} \; \begin{cases}
4 < x \\
-4/3 < x
\end{cases}$$

However, both need to be true, and since $-4/3 < 4$, only the first inequality is necessary to state.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Shouldn't it be ${-4\over 3}$? And what do you mean by "both need to be true, and since 4/3<4, only the first inequality is necessary to state."? I don't understand.

Comment: Yeah, you're right: $-(x+4) = -x-4$, so

$$-(x+4) < 2x \implies -x-4 < 2x \implies -\frac 4 3 < x$$

My point about the "both" is that we need both inequalities to be true, you could also say "inequality (1) and inequality (2) both hold", similar to how you did. So we know that

$$x > 4 \qquad \text{and} \qquad x > -\frac{4}{3}$$

What kind of $x$ satisfy both of these inequalities, though? It would only be the first kind of $x$, the $x$ that satisfy $x>4$.

Comment: So when we do problems like this, we must check the results because the algebra can lead us to solutions that don't necessarily work for both inequalities?

Comment: It depends on the method by which you solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Since $|x+4|\geq 0$ we get $\color{red}{2x> 0}$ so we can square the inequality:

$$ |x+4|^2< 4x^2\implies x^2+8x+16< 4x^2$$

or $$3x^2-8x-16> 0$$

Since $x_1 = 4$ and $x_2 = -{4\over 3}$ so $x\in \color{red}{\mathbb{R}^+\setminus[ -{4\over 3},4]}$.

Comment: The problem with squaring both sides is that you introduce extraneous solutions, effectively. This is obvious on looking [at the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uum6l8pxnn). For instance, sure, $x=-5$ satisfies $3x^2 - 8x - 16 > 0$, but not $|x+4| < 2x$.

Comment: You must intersect that solution with $(0,\infty)$ from the inequality $2x>0$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: It is. I did not notice the $+$ on the $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|x+4|<2x \implies 2x\ge 0$$
$$\implies x+4>0 \implies x+4<2x$$
$$\implies x>4$$

conversely

$$x>4\implies 0<x+4<2x $$
$$\implies |x+4|<2x$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$f(x)=2x-|x+4| = \begin{cases} 3x+ 4, & x < -4 \\ x-4, & x \ge 4\end{cases}$$
Obviously $f(x)$ is continuous, piecewise linear and strictly increasing, and $f(4)=0$. Therefore $$f(x) > 0 \iff x>4.$$